# Why are regenerative logic circuits called regenerative?

Tags: digital-logic

Why are regenerative logic circuits called regenerative? I know that regenerative means to generate again, but why is this word used to describe circuits like flip flops and latches?

Comment: Regeneration is just another name for positive feedback. Positive feedback is what allows you to create circuits with memory.

Comment: It can also be used with negative feedback depending on the application, so basically it means to generate delayed outputs using any feedback.

Comment: The delays may be in the forward or feedback path or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key aspect of circuits like latches is that they are digital, rather than analog. In order to achieve this, an noisy input signal with a voltage that can range from ground to \$V_{CC}\$ must be mapped to ground or \$V_{CC}\$. If the input is 0.75 \$V_{CC}\$, the output cannot be 0.75 \$V_{CC}\$, because that's an analog output, rather than digital. To achieve this conversion, latches use positive feedback to amplify the signal. In this way, inputs greater than some threshold will grow until they reach \$V_{CC}\$, and the opposite is true to. This falls under the principles of regenerative circuits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_circuit, but you can also think about how if a signal diminishes slightly due to losses, when you feed it into one of these logic circuit the signal "regenerates" its digital properties.

Comment: "...a frequency that can range from ground to Vcc"? Could you read through your answer and try to clarify the phrasing. How do you "parse" a voltage?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson frequency was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 0):

regenerative circuits make the fastest possible analog-comparators.

If the two sides are imbalanced by 1milliVolt, and each side has propagation delay of 1 nanosecond with gain of 10X, then in 2 nanoseconds the imbalance has become 100 milliVolts.

After another 2 nanoseconds, the imbalance has become 10 volts (or whatever is rail-rail output --- the logic outputs).

Given 100 ohms and 10pF is 1 nanosecond delay, and 300MHz Ftau transistors have delays of 0.16/300MHz  = 0.5 nanoseconds, the designer can take slow transistors and run them at high currents (10ma and 100 ohms produces 1 volt output, quite adequate for ECL).

In the 1960s a North Carolina company ---- Computer Labs, later bought by Analog Devices ---- would sell you a 10,000,000 conversion per second at 10 bits ADC. Had several stages (5?), with 2 bits per stage, using 2_bit_DACs and delay lines as needed, amplifers after each stage to boost the residual analog difference

Comment: The question does not ask about the speed of regenerative circuits, merely about their naming and description.